# How to put xpaths generated progmatically in object repository for unique element name

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have written a code using jsoup to get all the xpath of a webpage,by passing the URL of that webpage.
now i want to store all of these xpaths in an object repository with key as the element name and value as the xpath. to use them later with selenium.
Is there any way to get the unique key (element name) with which the associated xpath can be stored ?

i want to get this element name using java program.

i have tried it using element.tagName and element.nodeName but both of them are giving the HTML tag only.

Comment: I would suggest that you avoid using an object repository and instead use the page object model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("**URL**").get();    
Elements e = doc.select("*");    
for(Elements e1 : e):        
        String p = CSS2XPath.css2xpath(e1.cssSelector(), true);    
        System.out.println("XPath = " + p);
```

Comment: Hi Pranav Raikote,this i have done to get the xpaths.Now i have to store these xpaths in property file using key and value pair.that key needs to be an element name and should be unique.so i can use that name later on.how can i generate that element name?